# Change custom element displayed

Tags: javascript, element

I have made a web application which uses multiple pages. To go from one page to another, I was using window.location.href. As I didn't like this approach, I wanted to use Custom Element. I'm searching I way to change the current custom element displayed when we, for example, press next button. Does someone know a similar topic please?

index.html :

```
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

index.js :

```
window.customElements.define('connection-view', Connection);
//other custom element defined here like profile, ...

var root = document.querySelector('#root');
root.innerHTML = '<connection-view></connection-view>'
//when the button login is pressed, have to change this to profile component
```

Comment: I think what you're doing is calling 'routing', ie. how navigation works in your application. You don't need to worry about CustomElement at all, if you want something to look a certain way use CSS.

Comment: I don't really need routing, just simple button navigation. I want to use custom element to divise my components and make the code cleaner.

Comment: I recommend using ReactJS instead of WebComponents. You'll be able to find guides on how to do just about anything. To my knowledge nobody really uses WebComponents.

Comment: Thank you, sadly, I'm working with photoshop framework and React is not fully supported by it. But if web components are not the solution, I will search for another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a root div and then change his innerHTML with the custom element tag